# error in kivy first program how to rectify it?

Tags: python, kivy

```
import kivy

kivy.require('1.10.0')

from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.label import Label

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):

        return Label(text='Hello world')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    MyApp().run()
```

Error:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Ashu Sharma\.kivy\logs\kivy_17-10-03_0.txt

[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.0

[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:01:18) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]

[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded

[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_pil, img_gif (img_sdl2, img_ffpyplayer ignored)

[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: pil(['text_sdl2'] ignored)

[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider.
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

  File "C:\Users\Ashu Sharma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)

  File "C:\Users\Ashu Sharma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 26, in <module>
    from kivy.core.window._window_sdl2 import _WindowSDL2Storage

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
 Exception ignored in: 'kivy.properties.dpi2px'

 Traceback (most recent call last):

   File "C:\Users\Ashu Sharma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\utils.py", line 496, in __get__
     retval = self.func(inst)

   File "C:\Users\Ashu Sharma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\metrics.py", line 174, in dpi
     EventLoop.ensure_window()

   File "C:\Users\Ashu Sharma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 127, in ensure_window
     sys.exit(1)
 SystemExit: 1

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

Comment: Are you running .py file or did you change it to an exe file?

Comment: i m using .py file

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the **PIL** dependency, install it via

```
py -3.5 -m pip install pillow
```

*Pillow* is the **python3** **PIL** ...

Comment: same thing? maybe you have installed it on the wrong interpeter ?

Comment: see the error which i faced after the edit u have told me(ie after installing pillow).

Comment: now its an indentation problem with your **if \__name\__ ... "

Answer (score 0):

```
[CRITICAL] [Window ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider. sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

From official Kivy site:https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html

> Install the dependencies (skip gstreamer (~120MB) if not needed, see
>   Kivy’s dependencies):
>
> python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 **kivy.deps.sdl2**
>   kivy.deps.glew
>
> python -m pip install kivy.deps.gstreamer

especially **kivy.deps.sdl2**